# Divide long list into short lists of specified length in R

Tags: r, list

This is closely related to a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663125/divide-long-list-into-shorter-lists-in-r). However I need something slightly different...

I have a long list of objects that I need to divide into smaller lists, each with a certain number of entries. I need to be able to change the length of the lists for different tasks. The catch is that each object can only appear once in a single list.

```
# Create some example data... 
# Make a list of objects.
LIST <- c('Oranges', 'Toast', 'Truck', 'Dog', 'Hippo', 'Bottle', 'Hope', 'Mint', 'Red', 'Trees', 'Watch', 'Cup', 'Pencil', 'Lunch', 'Paper', 'Peanuts', 'Cloud', 'Forever', 'Ocean', 'Train', 'Fork', 'Moon', 'Horse', 'Parrot', 'Leaves', 'Book', 'Cheese', 'Tin', 'Bag', 'Socks', 'Lemons', 'Blue', 'Plane', 'Hammock', 'Roof', 'Wind', 'Green', 'Chocolate', 'Car', 'Distance')

# Generate a longer list, with a random sequence and number of repetitions for each entry.
set.seed(123)

LONG.LIST <- data.frame(Name = (sample(LIST, size = 200, replace = TRUE)))

print(LONG.LIST)

Name
1         Cup
2    Distance
3        Roof
4      Pencil
5       Lunch
6       Toast
7       Watch
8      Bottle
9         Car
10       Roof
11      Lunch
12    Forever
13     Cheese
14    Oranges
15      Ocean
16  Chocolate
17      Socks
18     Leaves
19    Oranges
20   Distance
21      Green
22      Paper
23        Red
24      Paper
25      Trees
26  Chocolate
27     Bottle
28        Dog
29       Wind
30     Parrot
etc....
```

For argument, suppose I wanted to create a series of 20-item lists. Using the example generated above, `'Distance'` appears at both position '2' and position '20', `'Lunch'` at both '5' and '11, and `'Oranges'` at '14' and 19', so the first list without duplicates would need to extend to include `'Green'`, `'Paper'` and `'Red'`. The second list would then begin with `'Paper'` at position 24. However I don't want to be restricted to a length of 20, sometimes I might want to make it 10 or 25.

Incorporating comments from @LAP below, which help to describe my problem; "Go through your vector until you found 20 unique items, put them together, discard the duplicates, then move on over your vector until you found the next 20 unique items, and so on until the end of your vector, filling the last part with `NA`.

"The separate lists only need to be unique in and of themselves. There may be duplicates between two or more lists."

The last list is likely to be incomplete, so it would be good to pad it with `'NA'`s. Ideally the entries would be alphabetical within each list.

The most useful output would be one-list per column in a dataframe.

Comment: It is not clear how you want to process.  For e.g. Roof appears on  3 and 10

Comment: Yes, and so then `Roof` should only appear once in the first list. If any item is duplicated then it should only appear once. But then if it can appear again in other lists

Comment: Suppose, if one of the elements in the LIST occurs at position 90 for the first time, then how do you split

Comment: It would depend on how many lists had been constructed before. If I wanted lists that were 20 entries long and there were no duplicates anywhere, then the 90th entry would be halfway through the 5th list.

Comment: When you use the word list, do you mean an actual `list` object, or is it a vector?

Comment: @LAP apologies, it is a vector in `LONG.LIST`

Comment: Perhaps `lapply(split(LONG.LIST, as.integer(gl(nrow(LONG.LIST), 20, nrow(LONG.LIST)))), unique)`

Comment: Hm, seems to give lists with differing lengths. None is more than 20, but instead 16, 15, 15 18 etc.

Comment: It splits by length 20 and then take the unique.  May be it is not clear to me yet.  That is the reason I said a reproducible example with set.seed and the expected output

Comment: I'm pretty sure the exact thing you want won't be possible without disproportional effort. If I understood you right, you want to: Go through your vector until you found 20 unique items, put them together, discard the duplicates, then move on over your vector until you found the next 20 unique items, and so on until the end of your vector, filling the last part with `NA`. Right?

Comment: Your `LIST` items are of length 34.  Did you meant any 20 unique ?

Comment: @LAP yes that is exactly right

Comment: Sorry, the problem is as @LAP describes in their comment. The code akrun wrote for the previous question I linked above worked well, but the lists were all of different lengths, and I couldn't work out how to specify the length.

Comment: Could you please the solution posted below..  After removing the duplicates, it is a list of 2 with 20 unique elements

Comment: I've just been testing it. I don't think it works as I hoped. It does create lists of the correct length, but each item only appears in a single list. There ought to be some items which appear in two or more lists.

Comment: Sorry, then I didn't understand the problem

Comment: The separate lists only need to be unique in and of themselves. There may be duplicates between two or more lists.

Comment: Precisely @LAP. I will edit the question to include your interpretations.

Comment: That is also what adds the difficulty to the request. You'd need a procedure that moves over the vector, constantly checking whether 20 unique items are already accumulated or not, then extract those items while maintaining the position of the vector you were at, and then start the procedure again for the remainder of the vector, discarding the duplicates up to that point.

Comment: It could be `LONG.LIST %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% arrange(n) %>% split(list(as.integer(gl(nrow(.), 20, nrow(.)), n, drop = TRUE)))`

Comment: Your last subset has duplicates @akrun. Besides that it seems to work.

Comment: You are right.  It has to do with the splitting.  But, I am just throwing some ideas to understand it better

Comment: It's getting closer, but I'm not absolutely sure it works yet... The items still seem to be appearing in order though, going through all 40 items and then starting a new list. Sorry, how can I use `set.seed` to help create a reproducible example?

Comment: just set some seed before using the `sample` command, like `set.seed(123); LONG.LIST <- data.frame(Name = (sample(LIST, size = 200, replace = TRUE)))`

Comment: Thanks @LAP. So now, if we try akrun's code, the first two lists have 40 unique entries. There's no duplication until the third list. (I've added `data.frame()` around the call to make it easier to compare the lists)

Comment: From a theoretical point of view, you'd need a combination of a `while` loop (check whether unique subset is of length 20) and a `for` loop (go through your `LONG.LIST`). I fail to get this combination to work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, this is a partial answer, as I think I've got most of what you need.

Note that this may be slow with huge data.

First you initialize a list with as many empty vectors as you want groups afterwards. In this example we want to create 10 groups of 20 from a vector of 200 items.

First, we create reproducible data:

```
LIST <- c('Oranges', 'Toast', 'Truck', 'Dog', 'Hippo', 'Bottle', 'Hope', 'Mint', 'Red', 
          'Trees', 'Watch', 'Cup', 'Pencil', 'Lunch', 'Paper', 'Peanuts', 'Cloud', 'Forever', 
          'Ocean', 'Train', 'Fork', 'Moon', 'Horse', 'Parrot', 'Leaves', 'Book', 'Cheese', 
          'Tin', 'Bag', 'Socks', 'Lemons', 'Blue', 'Plane', 'Hammock', 'Roof', 'Wind', 'Green', 
          'Chocolate', 'Car', 'Distance')

set.seed(123)

LONG.LIST <- data.frame(Name = (sample(LIST, size = 200, replace = TRUE)), stringsAsFactors = F)

test <- vector("list", 10)
```

Then you initialize two counters:

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
```

Now we use a `while` loop that runs until `i` is greater than the number of items in our vector to be splitted (so it stops when `i > 200`). Within this loop we check whether the current subvector `j` in our list is shorter than 20. If so, we add an item and deduplicate, if not, we add 1 to `j` to jump into the next subvector.

```
while(i <= nrow(LONG.LIST)){
  if(length(test[[j]]) < 20){
      test[[j]] <- c(test[[j]], LONG.LIST$Name[i])
      test[[j]] <- unique(test[[j]])
      i <- i+1
  }else{
      j <- j+1
    }
}
```

And this is our result:

```
> test
[[1]]
 [1] "Lunch"     "Cheese"    "Truck"     "Roof"      "Hope"      "Mint"      "Lemons"    "Pencil"    "Hippo"     "Moon"     
[11] "Car"       "Chocolate" "Trees"     "Distance"  "Dog"       "Bag"       "Paper"     "Peanuts"   "Ocean"     "Wind"     

[[2]]
 [1] "Hippo"     "Wind"      "Mint"      "Plane"     "Trees"     "Truck"     "Lemons"    "Watch"     "Chocolate" "Train"    
[11] "Dog"       "Lunch"     "Green"     "Horse"     "Toast"     "Distance"  "Cloud"     "Hammock"   "Fork"      "Paper"    

[[3]]
 [1] "Watch"     "Hope"      "Paper"     "Socks"     "Bag"       "Plane"     "Bottle"    "Green"     "Lunch"     "Fork"     
[11] "Mint"      "Hippo"     "Chocolate" "Car"       "Trees"     "Toast"     "Forever"   "Red"       "Wind"      "Ocean"    

[[4]]
 [1] "Car"      "Lunch"    "Toast"    "Lemons"   "Moon"     "Socks"    "Hippo"    "Pencil"   "Blue"     "Fork"     "Paper"   
[12] "Distance" "Cloud"    "Train"    "Wind"     "Watch"    "Bottle"   "Forever"  "Green"    "Bag"     

[[5]]
 [1] "Train"   "Cheese"  "Bottle"  "Fork"    "Paper"   "Green"   "Leaves"  "Blue"    "Toast"   "Parrot"  "Lemons"  "Dog"    
[13] "Hammock" "Ocean"   "Red"     "Peanuts" "Pencil"  "Bag"     "Horse"   "Hope"   

[[6]]
 [1] "Oranges"   "Truck"     "Hippo"     "Trees"     "Parrot"    "Red"       "Hope"      "Cloud"     "Tin"       "Bag"      
[11] "Pencil"    "Cup"       "Dog"       "Leaves"    "Chocolate" "Mint"      "Plane"     "Moon"      "Fork"      "Green"    

[[7]]
 [1] "Tin"       "Mint"      "Book"      "Bag"       "Roof"      "Hope"      "Socks"     "Watch"     "Paper"     "Peanuts"  
[11] "Cup"       "Distance"  "Leaves"    "Bottle"    "Cloud"     "Horse"     "Trees"     "Oranges"   "Chocolate" "Toast"    

[[8]]
[1] "Horse"     "Watch"     "Chocolate" "Tin"       "Red"       "Train"    

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL
```

Now we only need to fill the last vectors with `NA`. This can probably done differently, but it gets the job done:

```
for(i in 1:length(test)){
  if(length(test[[i]]) < 20){
    test[[i]] <- c(test[[i]], rep(NA, 20 - length(test[[i]])))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LAP! It looks like it is working nicely. Is it possible to return a dataframe rather than a list of lists? (I know I can `list2env` and then `rbind`, but I think there should be a neater method)

Comment: You can use `do.call(rbind, test)`.

Comment: I actually opted for `data.frame(do.call(cbind, test))` to get what I wanted. Thanks for all of your efforts!

Comment: You are welcome. It was actually a nice challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential answer, its not pretty but I think it is what you are after:

first the data:

```
LIST <- c('Oranges', 'Toast', 'Truck', 'Dog', 'Hippo', 'Bottle', 'Hope', 
         'Mint', 'Red', 'Trees', 'Watch', 'Cup', 'Pencil', 'Lunch', 'Paper', 
         'Peanuts', 'Cloud', 'Forever', 'Ocean', 'Train', 'Fork', 'Moon', 
         'Horse', 'Parrot', 'Leaves', 'Book', 'Cheese', 'Tin', 'Bag', 
         'Socks', 'Lemons', 'Blue', 'Plane', 'Hammock', 'Roof', 'Wind', 
         'Green', 'Chocolate', 'Car', 'Distance')

set.seed(123)
LONG.LIST <- data.frame(Name = (sample(LIST, size = 200, replace = TRUE)))
```

create a function that will find 20 unique elements from the top of the data frame and split the data frame according to that into two list elements:

```
library(tidyverse)

spliter <- function(df){
  df  %>%
  as.tibble()%>%
    mutate(Name = as.character(Name),
           dup = !duplicated(Name),
           cum = cumsum(dup),
           splt = ifelse(cum <= 20, 0, 1)) %>%
    {split(df, .$splt)} 
}
```

now apply this function to the second element of the resulting list until there is nothing to split removing duplicates in each list element:

```
b <- spliter(LONG.LIST)
c1 <- list(b[[1]] %>%
            filter(!duplicated(Name)))

i <- 1
while(length(b) != 1){
  i <- i+1
  b <- spliter(b[[2]])

  c1[[i]] <- b[[1]] %>%
    filter(!duplicated(Name))
}
```

Fill the last element with NA if needed:

```
c1 <- lapply(c1, function(x){
  if(nrow(x) <  20){
    data.frame(Name = c(as.character(x$Name), rep(NA_character_, (20-length(x$Name)))))
  } else( x)
})
```

combine to data frame:

```
do.call(cbind, c1)

        Name    Name     Name      Name     Name    Name      Name
1        Cup   Green     Wind      Mint     Book Hammock    Parrot
2       Blue     Tin    Paper    Bottle   Pencil   Trees   Hammock
3      Cloud    Blue   Cheese    Cheese      Red     Dog    Pencil
4       Wind Oranges      Dog     Lunch    Paper   Socks       Bag
5  Chocolate   Train  Peanuts    Pencil Distance   Train     Watch
6      Toast  Lemons    Watch      Blue     Hope Peanuts     Train
7       Moon     Red    Plane       Dog      Dog   Hippo     Horse
8      Horse  Pencil  Forever     Ocean   Bottle   Horse     Green
9      Ocean   Trees     Blue      Fork      Tin     Red  Distance
10       Car  Bottle   Lemons    Parrot   Leaves Forever    Leaves
11       Tin   Cloud     Book     Train     Wind    Fork Chocolate
12     Hippo   Paper      Bag       Car   Cheese   Paper     Ocean
13     Trees    Hope  Oranges      Wind    Socks    Book     Cloud
14     Lunch   Ocean    Train     Green     Fork    Moon    Cheese
15      Book   Watch      Red    Leaves    Plane   Cloud      Hope
16  Distance    Roof   Leaves     Cloud     Blue   Watch      <NA>
17    Cheese   Toast    Hippo Chocolate  Forever    Mint      <NA>
18       Bag Forever    Trees     Truck    Cloud    Roof      <NA>
19    Parrot   Hippo    Cloud       Bag  Oranges  Cheese      <NA>
20    Bottle   Horse Distance      Moon     Mint  Leaves      <NA>
```

Here is a function like in ngm's answer:

```
miss <- function(y, split){
  require(tidyverse)
  spliter <- function(df){
    df  %>%
      as.tibble()%>%
      mutate(Name = as.character(Name),
             dup = !duplicated(Name),
             cum = cumsum(dup),
             splt = ifelse(cum <= split, 0, 1)) %>%
             {split(df, .$splt)} 
    }
  b <- spliter(y)
  c1 <- list(b[[1]] %>%
            filter(!duplicated(Name)))
  i <- 1
  while(length(b) != 1){
    i <- i+1
    b <- spliter(b[[2]])

      c1[[i]] <- b[[1]] %>%
        filter(!duplicated(Name))
      }
  c1 <- lapply(c1, function(x){
    if(nrow(x) <  20){
      data.frame(Name = c(as.character(x$Name), rep(NA_character_, (20-length(x$Name)))))
      } else( x)
    })
  return(do.call(cbind, c1))
}
```

usage:

```
miss(LONG.LIST, 20 )
```

Comment: Thanks @missuse, but it doesn't seem to behave as expected. `b` is two lists, the first of 31 items and the second of 169. Then `c` is just a duplicate of the list of 31. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: Apologies, I was too hasty, you are correct; `c` is a list of 8 elements. However, each element of `c` appears to be of different lengths. How could I extract them to individual lists, or even columns in a single dataframe?

Comment: Hm, my output doesn't look like that though. `c` is 8 lists with 28, 27, 26, 27... etc. entries

Comment: Ok, now I understand. So I need to add some sort of `unique()` in there to get the lists of items without duplicates that I can then combine to a dataframe?

Comment: Updated my answer with the requested output.

Comment: all three answers provide different output on the same data I think you should check in detail which result you are interested in. @LAP's and mine are similar, but there is one distinction regarding the bordering words, I think his solution is more in line with the requested output. ngm's solution is something completely different.

Comment: You are correct, I needed some more time to test them all. Your approach is neater, (output as columns in a dataframe and it doesn't have lots of extra columns of NAs afterwards). However, you are right about the 'bordering' words, and LAP's answer behaves as I want it to. Thank you for your efforts though!

Answer (score 1):

This function `svu` ("split vector unique") takes a vector and produces a data frame according to your specifications.

I didn't see why the input would be a list or a data frame. It seems more natural to make the input a vector.

```
words <- c('Oranges', 'Toast', 'Truck', 'Dog', 'Hippo', 'Bottle', 'Hope', 'Mint', 'Red', 'Trees', 'Watch', 'Cup', 'Pencil', 'Lunch', 'Paper', 'Peanuts', 'Cloud', 'Forever', 'Ocean', 'Train', 'Fork', 'Moon', 'Horse', 'Parrot', 'Leaves', 'Book', 'Cheese', 'Tin', 'Bag', 'Socks', 'Lemons', 'Blue', 'Plane', 'Hammock', 'Roof', 'Wind', 'Green', 'Chocolate', 'Car', 'Distance')
set.seed(123)
more_words <- sample(words, size = 200, replace = TRUE)

# x is the original vector and n is the desired number of 
# words in each column of the resulting data frame.
svu <- function(x, n) {
  # How many eventual columns?
  n_cols <- trunc(length(x)/n)
  # That many eventual columns all filled with NA for now.
  vec_list <- lapply(1:n_cols, function(x) rep(NA, n))

  # For each word...
  for(string in x) {
    for(i in 1:n_cols) {
      if(!(string %in% vec_list[[i]]) && sum(is.na(vec_list[[i]])) > 0) {
        # ...add it to a non-full column not containing that word.
        vec_list[[i]][min(which(is.na(vec_list[[i]])))] <- string
        break
      }
    }
  }
  # Make it a data frame
  data.frame(do.call(cbind, vec_list), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Try it out:

```
svu(more_words, 20)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#>           X1      X2      X3       X4        X5        X6       X7
#> 1        Cup    Wind    Wind     Wind      Wind     Plane     Wind
#> 2       Blue   Ocean     Car   Bottle     Plane   Forever   Bottle
#> 3      Cloud   Horse     Tin    Watch   Forever      Wind   Pencil
#> 4       Wind   Toast   Cloud    Plane      Blue    Cheese Distance
#> 5  Chocolate     Car  Bottle  Forever     Hippo      Mint     Hope
#> 6      Toast     Tin   Trees     Blue      Mint      Blue      Dog
#> 7       Moon    Moon   Ocean   Lemons    Bottle     Lunch      Tin
#> 8      Horse     Cup   Watch     Book    Cheese     Train   Leaves
#> 9      Ocean   Green    Roof      Bag     Lunch    Bottle   Cheese
#> 10       Car    Blue   Toast  Oranges    Pencil    Pencil    Socks
#> 11       Tin Oranges Forever    Train       Dog     Truck     Fork
#> 12     Hippo   Train    Blue      Red     Ocean Chocolate    Plane
#> 13     Trees  Lemons   Hippo  Peanuts      Fork       Bag     Blue
#> 14     Lunch     Red   Horse   Leaves    Parrot      Moon  Forever
#> 15      Book  Pencil     Red    Paper     Train       Car    Cloud
#> 16  Distance   Trees  Lemons    Hippo       Car    Parrot  Oranges
#> 17    Cheese  Bottle   Paper    Trees     Green     Cloud     Mint
#> 18       Bag   Cloud  Cheese   Cheese    Leaves      Book  Hammock
#> 19    Parrot   Paper     Dog    Cloud     Cloud       Red    Trees
#> 20    Bottle    Hope Peanuts Distance Chocolate     Paper    Train
#>          X8      X9       X10
#> 1      Wind    Wind     Trees
#> 2    Pencil  Pencil     Paper
#> 3    Bottle   Trees       Red
#> 4    Cheese Peanuts     Socks
#> 5  Distance     Red      Roof
#> 6     Trees   Paper    Pencil
#> 7       Dog   Socks    Parrot
#> 8     Socks    Book     Watch
#> 9   Hammock    Mint     Green
#> 10  Peanuts    Roof  Distance
#> 11    Hippo  Cheese    Leaves
#> 12    Horse  Leaves Chocolate
#> 13      Red    Moon     Ocean
#> 14  Forever  Parrot     Cloud
#> 15     Fork Hammock    Cheese
#> 16    Paper     Bag      Hope
#> 17     Book   Watch     Horse
#> 18     Moon   Train      <NA>
#> 19    Cloud   Horse      <NA>
#> 20    Watch   Green      <NA>
```

Comment: This looks very neat, thanks! But when I ran it no `data.frame` was produced?

Comment: Did you run something like `svu(more_words, 20)`?

Comment: Thanks for this. On further testing however, it doesn't seem to behave as I would expect. The first column fills correctly, but then something strange seems to happen. The output should be similar to LAP and missuse's answers (they differ according to the 'bordering' words, but this behaviour makes sense - see comment below missuse's solution). But this solution seems to give something completely different.

Comment: Your question was a bit of a moving target. My solution uses as many words as possible from `more_words` putting duplicates in the next possible subsample as you go along. At some point during the discussion you added the requirement to just discard duplicates as they are encountered.